# Set Permission on Custom module in magento

Tags: magento

I have created a new module in Magento. It works well, but issue is:

I have created a USER for the client to login as,
and have assigned it to a ROLE, under `System -> Permissions -> Role`.

When the user logins he can see the `TABS > custom modules links`,
but the links of custom modules do not work.

Is there an issue with this? (it works perfectly fine, with the ADMIN credentials)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you haven't define ACL under `<adminhtml>` tag in config.xml
Checkout http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration for more details

Comment: i also define the  <acl></acl> tag in config.xml file,but nothing happened.

Comment: can you share your config.xml file here ?

Comment: yup, but how to share as beacuse that was too long ,,and this comment box is limited to post , plz let me know the convenient way to share the config.xml ?

Comment: Ok then first checkout above link and still any confusion then share only <adminhtml> tag.

Comment: <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <admintab module="admintab">
                <title>Banner</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="admintab">
                        <title>Manage Image</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>admintab/adminhtml_admintab</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </admintab>
        </menu>

Comment: <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <admintab>
                            <title>admintab Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </admintab>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>   
        </acl>

Comment: <layout>
            <updates>
                <admintab>
                    <file>admintab.xml</file>
                </admintab>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>